# Can't open Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Every time I try to open Visual Studio for Mac, it bounces and tells me that it had to quit unexpectedly. In several forums tells me to delete the "addin-db-002" folder from `~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/7.0/` but that didn't help me at all. I updated the XCode and the Visual Studio too, but I keep getting the error message.

Here is the log:

```
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: Starting Visual Studio 2017 for Mac 7.6.8 (build 38)
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: Build Information
Release ID: 706080038
Git revision: f4178f550a4de7c03aa23678041abe4fc388cf72
Build date: 2018-09-28 14:21:41+00
Build branch: release-7.6
Xamarin extensions: 051b653186a95ced1c127dfd8c358df1b9315d0d

INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: Running on Mono 5.12.0.309 (2018-02/39d89a335c8) (64-bit)
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: Operating System: Mac OS X 10.13.6
Darwin 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0
    Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018
    root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: Initializing ms error reporting app: com.microsoft.visual-studio, Visual Studio, 7.6.8.38
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]:                                    : /Applications/Visual Studio.app
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:16Z]: GTK: Using gtkrc from /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/gtkrc.mac-dark
Could not find `PresentationCore` referenced by assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.
Could not find `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImageCatalog` referenced by assembly `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:17Z]: Accessibility disabled
WARNING [2018-10-04 00:53:17Z]: Gtk-Warning: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Stack trace: 
  at Gtk.Application.gtk_init (System.Int32& , System.IntPtr& ) [0x00000] in <13dfc6c534074eb08a8f382a81e605d5>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.do_init (System.String progname, System.String[]& args, System.Boolean check) [0x0004d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/gtk-sharp-None/gtk/Application.cs:102 
  at Gtk.Application.Init (System.String progname, System.String[]& args) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/gtk-sharp-None/gtk/Application.cs:131 
  at MonoDevelop.Components.IdeTheme.InitializeGtk (System.String progname, System.String[]& args) [0x000ec] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components/IdeTheme.cs:95 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x001a2] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:140 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args, MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer customizer) [0x000b2] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:804 
  at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/md-addins/Xamarin.Startup/Main.cs:11 
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:17Z]: Using GTK+ 2.24.23
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Ide
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MacPlatform
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Initializing Runtime Mono 5.12.0.309
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: [0 (+0)] Finding custom frameworks
Starting Visual Studio
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Using Xamarin.Mac 4.4.1.178 (master / eeaeb7e6)
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: [59 (+59)] Creating frameworks
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: [142 (+83)] Initializing frameworks
   Loading Workbench
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: [164 (+22)] END: Target runtimes loaded
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xml
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Refactoring
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PackageManagement
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.UnitTesting
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.TextTemplating
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNet
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.PerformanceDiagnostics
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.VsCodeDebugProtocol
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DotNetCore
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.TestCloud
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Xamarin.Ide.Mac
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Interactive.XS.Xamarin.Interactive
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MacDev
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.MonoMac
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.IPhone
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.GtkCore
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.ConnectedServices
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Ide.Identity
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.AzureSupport
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Packaging
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.TestCloud.NUnit
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Mac.RazorAddin
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebTools.WebToolingAddin
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Designer
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.iOSDesigner
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.AndroidDesigner
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.FormsPreviewer
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: Xamarin.Live.Player
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AspNetCore
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: DotNetCore.Debugger
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Docker
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.AzureFunctions
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WebReferences
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.DocFood
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Unity
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.WakaTime
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: AndroidKeystoreSignatureTool.AndroidSigTool
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:18Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.TFS
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: ANDROID: Found Xamarin.Android 9.0.0.20
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: ANDROID: Found Xamarin.Android 9.0.0.20
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: Found Xcode, version 10.0 (14320.25).
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: Found Xamarin.iOS, version 12.0.0.15.
      Initializing Main Window
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: Creating DefaultWorkbench
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: Found MonoMac.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:19Z]: Found Xamarin.Mac, version 5.0.0.0.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:20Z]: Updating Welcome Page News from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846107'.
ERROR [2018-10-04 00:53:20Z]: An unhandled exception has occurred. Terminating Visual Studio? False
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Success
  at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.SocketClient+<ConnectAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00231] in <77315aa4fd5d49b8add7ad003b8a13a2>:0 
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:21Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:21Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
10/4/2018 4:53:21 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:22Z]: [Inspector] Initializing
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:22Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.VBBinding
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:22Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.NUnit
WARNING [2018-10-04 00:53:22Z]: [Wakatime Info 12:53:22 AM] Initializing WakaTime v3.0.5.0

INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:23Z]: Refreshing profile info
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:23Z]: Fetching auth token for Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com.
WARNING [2018-10-04 00:53:23Z]: [Wakatime Info 12:53:23 AM] Finished initializing WakaTime v3.0.5.0

10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AuthenticationContext.cs: ADAL PCL.Mac with assembly version '3.13.4.0', file version '3.13.4.0' and informational version '' is running...
10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/authorize/
    Resource: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
    ClientId: 872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Cross Tenant refresh token was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: A matching item (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:23 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Refreshing access token...
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: f087e781-40c5-4a6d-b414-e08ca9b64eca - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: wifxIZKTo4s2wB+GX1Jwgnh6BEEFv4R6FjNjN/xf6a8=
    Expiration Time: 10/4/2018 5:53:24 AM +00:00
    User Hash: oLRPwa141Sh3iBORINYL6TB4ToArb5DzOK/lgn8jnAU=

10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/authorize/
    Resource: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
    ClientId: 872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Cross Tenant refresh token was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: A matching item (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Refreshing access token...
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:24Z]: Got token to fetch profile info with
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 26e42ea3-f6ef-431a-bad8-975d24dc9f6b - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: ZbjGCO3XLtQ9qSzR34CYKvtBduFh9nufkye03MBUUfE=
    Expiration Time: 10/4/2018 5:53:23 AM +00:00
    User Hash: oLRPwa141Sh3iBORINYL6TB4ToArb5DzOK/lgn8jnAU=

10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/authorize/
    Resource: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
    ClientId: 872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Cross Tenant refresh token was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: A matching item (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:24 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Refreshing access token...
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: 5b6a54ab-3360-4754-a9d3-9d7062b59437 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: 43wIovraPhM5SUNtt2u16iVRb2JZ3T2wAG7Jj7TbqpY=
    Expiration Time: 10/4/2018 5:53:24 AM +00:00
    User Hash: oLRPwa141Sh3iBORINYL6TB4ToArb5DzOK/lgn8jnAU=

10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/authorize/
    Resource: 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
    ClientId: 872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1
    CacheType: null
    Authentication Target: User

10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Cross Tenant refresh token was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: A matching item (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:25 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Refreshing access token...
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:25Z]: Silently creating the profile.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM: f0f1c8f0-2625-499f-888c-afff65267319 - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: wBkWxwleT78LAk1PXH0ZGyYsKxcGEfl5ccgnS2J98fk=
    Expiration Time: 10/4/2018 5:53:25 AM +00:00
    User Hash: oLRPwa141Sh3iBORINYL6TB4ToArb5DzOK/lgn8jnAU=

10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
10/4/2018 4:53:26 AM:  - /Users/jsuarezruiz/Proyectos/vs4mac-tfvc/src/ADAL.PCL/ADAL.PCL/TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Fetching vsid...
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Refreshing entitlements...
Error: did not find one of the files in sources//Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/monodoc/MonoTouch-man
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Found cached entitlements
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Found cached entitlements
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Welcome Page News already up-to-date.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:26Z]: Updating Welcome Page News from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846107'.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Profile did not exist. Created one for 'Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com'.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Getting large avatar
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Got large avatar. Checking for null: 'True'
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Getting the display name
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Welcome Page News already up-to-date.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:27Z]: Got the display name: Diomedes Ignacio Dominguez Ureña
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:29Z]: Unable to parse version from directory. '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:29Z]: Fetching updater auth token.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:29Z]: Fetching auth token for Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Querying Update for: Stable
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Checking for updates: https://software.xamarin.com/Service/Updates?v=2&m=4148a6eb-c87b-49b3-9876-5b804a72aa70&pvd1ec039f-f3db-468b-a508-896d7c382999=1535485227&pv34937104-97FC-42A0-9159-D951135F72CA=706080038&pv88DE1F16-3942-4EF0-A123-F542E1950A10=8&pv964ebddd-1ffe-47e7-8128-5ce17ffffb05=512000309&pv4BBD2407-C3ED-4D32-B8CB-0559C7610697=1006003456&pv42a8c70f-b3dc-42f4-b8a5-435a1bb2410c=1531171025&pv0ab364ff-c0e9-43a8-8747-3afb02dc7731=2050000000&pv4569c276-1397-4adb-9485-82a7696df22e=2120000015&pvc07628e8-5521-4c1a-aa3a-f860e664f0a9=2013020000&os=osx-10.13.6&env=MonoDroidInstalled,MonoTouchInstalled,iphsdk12.0
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching updater auth token.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching auth token for Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Querying Update for: Beta
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Checking for updates: https://software.xamarin.com/Service/Updates?v=2&m=4148a6eb-c87b-49b3-9876-5b804a72aa70&pvd1ec039f-f3db-468b-a508-896d7c382999=1535485227&pv34937104-97FC-42A0-9159-D951135F72CA=706080038&pv88DE1F16-3942-4EF0-A123-F542E1950A10=8&pv964ebddd-1ffe-47e7-8128-5ce17ffffb05=512000309&pv4BBD2407-C3ED-4D32-B8CB-0559C7610697=1006003456&pv42a8c70f-b3dc-42f4-b8a5-435a1bb2410c=1531171025&pv0ab364ff-c0e9-43a8-8747-3afb02dc7731=2050000000&pv4569c276-1397-4adb-9485-82a7696df22e=2120000015&pvc07628e8-5521-4c1a-aa3a-f860e664f0a9=2013020000&level=Beta&alevel=Stable&os=osx-10.13.6&env=MonoDroidInstalled,MonoTouchInstalled,iphsdk12.0
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching updater auth token.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching auth token for Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Querying Update for: Alpha
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Checking for updates: https://software.xamarin.com/Service/Updates?v=2&m=4148a6eb-c87b-49b3-9876-5b804a72aa70&pvd1ec039f-f3db-468b-a508-896d7c382999=1535485227&pv34937104-97FC-42A0-9159-D951135F72CA=706080038&pv88DE1F16-3942-4EF0-A123-F542E1950A10=8&pv964ebddd-1ffe-47e7-8128-5ce17ffffb05=512000309&pv4BBD2407-C3ED-4D32-B8CB-0559C7610697=1006003456&pv42a8c70f-b3dc-42f4-b8a5-435a1bb2410c=1531171025&pv0ab364ff-c0e9-43a8-8747-3afb02dc7731=2050000000&pv4569c276-1397-4adb-9485-82a7696df22e=2120000015&pvc07628e8-5521-4c1a-aa3a-f860e664f0a9=2013020000&level=Alpha&alevel=Stable&os=osx-10.13.6&env=MonoDroidInstalled,MonoTouchInstalled,iphsdk12.0
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching updater auth token.
INFO [2018-10-04 00:53:31Z]: Fetching auth token for Diomedes.Dominguez-Urena@studentpartner.com.
```

Comment: The macOS crash log is not really that helpful since it does not show the managed (.NET) callstack for the crash. Can you post the IDE log from the ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/7.0 directory?

Comment: @MattWard, which one of this file can I share? https://i.postimg.cc/Hs322BTq/Screen-Shot-2018-11-25-at-1-57-39-PM.png

Comment: The latest Ide.log that is created, such as Ide.2018-10-04_00-53-16.log

Answer (score 1):

At the end I have to complete uninstall the VS for Mac, according to https://superuser.com/a/1237839/815258.

Comment: Same here. VS on Mac is a joke.